# google authenticator php

Tags: php, аутентификация, google-authenticator

Хочу использовать на сайте аутентификацию от гугла. Использую эту библиотеку - [ссылка](https://github.com/chregu/GoogleAuthenticator.php)

Все генерируется, приложение считывает код, но при проверке код не совпадает. Пробовал разные приложения, все они показывают один и тот же код, из-за этого решил, что проблема в сервере. Может кто сталкивался с таким?

Answer (score 0):

Проверь время на смартфоне. Для anroid есть программа ClockSync. 
Код зависит от времени. Расхождение в 30 секунд делает его нерабочим

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй поменять временную зону на сервере.
php.ini -> date.timezone ="YOUR TIMEZONE".
Также попробуй поменять время на устройстве где стоит Google Authenticator.